# Эмуляция нажатий клавиш в Python 3

Tags: python, winapi

Как cэмулировать нажатие клавишы Пробел в Python 3 на Windows?

Comment: Всмысле сэмулировать? Послать какому-либо окну сообщение о нажатии  пробела? Напишите конкретную задачу, которую вы хотите решить

Comment: Это все делается  для игры, в игре кавиша пробел - выстрел, нужно, чтобы программа с определенным интервалов нажимаа её

Comment: То есть вам надо послать сообщение о нажатом пробеле в другую программу, я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем есть 2 пути. Первый: использовать библиотеку [PyWin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). Второй: напрямую использовать функции WinAPI из библиотек Windows (User32.dll в данном случае). Я выбрал второй путь, так как у меня в Python3.6 в pip не оказалось библиотеки PyWin32.

```
from ctypes import *
import sys

is_64bit_arch = sys.maxsize > 2**32 # здесь определяется разрядность архитектуры

# ниже я просто определили необходимые типы для удобства
LONG_PTR = c_longlong if is_64bit_arch else c_long
UINT_PTR = c_ulonglong if is_64bit_arch else c_uint
UINT = c_uint
HANDLE = c_void_p
WPARAM = UINT_PTR
LPARAM = LONG_PTR
LRESULT = LONG_PTR
HWND = HANDLE
LPCSTR = c_char_p
DWORD = c_ulong
WORD = c_ushort
SendMessage = windll.user32.SendMessageA
FindWindow = windll.user32.FindWindowA
MapVirtualKey = windll.user32.MapVirtualKeyA

# непосредственно функция, которая принимает виртуальный код клавиши 
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx
def press_key(key_vk, window_title):
    c_window_title = LPCSTR(window_title.encode('utf-8'))

    WM_KEYUP = UINT(0x0101)
    WM_KEYDOWN = UINT(0x0100)
    wParam = WPARAM(key_vk)
    key_sc = MapVirtualKey(key_vk, 0)
    lParam = LPARAM(0x1 | (key_sc << 16))
    lParamDown = LPARAM(1 + (key_sc << 16) + (1 << 30))
    lParamUp = LPARAM(1 + (3 << 30) + (key_sc << 16))
    # находим хендл окна
    handle = FindWindow(LPCSTR(), c_window_title) 
    # отправляем сообщение о нажатии клавиши
    SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, wParam, lParamDown) 
    # отправляем сообщение об отпускании клавиши
    return SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, wParam, lParamUp) 

# пример вызова функции. Код 0x20 это пробел. Как видите, я отправлял
# сообщение в плеер, и видео останавливалось и продолжалось :)
press_key(0x20, "House of Cards S05E13 - VLC media player")
```

Собственно документацию по необходимым функциям можно найти на MSDN: [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), [MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx), [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Есть модуль, который позволяет скриптам Python управлять мышью и клавиатурой.
Ознакомиться с ним можно [здесь](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
А вот код, который поможет решить тебе эту задачу:

```py
import pyautogui

a = int(input("Кол-во нажатий: ") )
num = 0
                   
while num <= a:
    pyautogui.keyDown('SPACE')
    print(num)
    num += 1
```

Как видишь, я реализовал это с помощью pyautogui.